# How do the fell arms work?

Tags: tales-of-vesperia-de

I know the locations and how to 'unlock' them by killing the final boss, that part is the same in the 360 version. I also know that you make them more powerful by getting the killing blow on enemies.

At what point do they start getting more powerful? After you finish the story don't you start a new game+? After killing the final boss, do you have a choice to go to the new post-game dungeons and start making them more powerful?

In regards to the grade shop, do they carry over when you select 'all weapons' in the grade shop? Can I carry over their power to a new game+ and have them unlocked with them powered up at the start of a new game?

How exactly do these weapons work in regards to the the story and carrying over their power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fell arms, when unlocked, will get the bonus damage for enemies defeated immediately, and includes all enemies defeated up to the point of unlocking them. You can then use the unlocked fell arms on that same save for any of the post game or dungeons or any other quests/locations left to clean up, or in a new game+.

The bonuses from the unlocked fell arms are not always evident, as the unlocked versions show 0 stats when viewed in the menu, unequipped. By equipping the item, you can see the true pAtk and mAtk being granted by the arm's ability. You can also confirm this by noting the character's pAtk and mAtk before and after equipping the fell arm.

You can carry over the fell arms to new game+ through the grade shop by carrying over items (cost of 500 grade). As of the PS3 version (and hence the definitive version release as well), there is also the option in the grade shop to carry over the fell arm abilities, with the Inherit Fell Arm Ability option (cost of 1000 grade).

Reference: 
http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/ToV_-_Grade_Shop
https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/xbox360/945075-tales-of-vesperia/answers/25562-do-the-fell-arms-become-stronger-after-you-get-them

Comment: AH - you have to combine the "carry over items" along with "carry over fell arm power" in the grade shop. I was very confused and didn't put these two things together. Thanks